# How to get the rendered Sitecore page html from a pipeline without making a webrequest to the application itself?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore8, sitecore7

For a Business question, I have created one specific detail page. Based on querystring parameters contents could be changed  (dynamic contents are fetched from Datasource Repository by id) e.g.

```
*http://localhost/page/detail?id={88A1AA95-633D-4B0E-AAC7-BA0610F0V091}*
```

This is not SEO-friendly, so I created a pipeline to fetch the contents in a nicer way. I am using the Sitecore WebUtil to make a request to the application itself.

```
var content = WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage("http://localhost/page/detail?id={88A1AA95-633D-4B0E-AAC7-BA0610F0V091}")
```

It's working, but I am asking myself if there is a better way to resolve the rendered page html. I do not like the webrequest to the application itself. 
Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks in advance,
Jordy

Comment: So you want to have a nice and friendly url like 'http://localhost/page/details/nice-url-address' and based on that last segment of the url you want to render different page? Or based on that you want to inject only a part of the html from another page?

Comment: I want to get the HTML result of this url http://localhost/page/detail?id={88A1AA95-633D-4B0E-AAC7-BA0610F0V091} without making a webrequest to the application itself. I created the logic for the nice url already, so that's not part of this question.

Comment: I'm asking about what is the purpose because I don't think it's possible to make sure that page is rendered as it would be rendered for an user without doing a request. But maybe there is an easier option - just let us know the whole picture.

Comment: I think it's more efficient to not make a webrequest to the application itself. The request is already there based on the nice url, i am looking for a direction to resolve the html internally by for example executing some logic which is responsible for rendering the html and inject (forward and manipulate) for example the HTTP-context?

Comment: I think you may want to look at https://www.google.com/search?q=sitecore+custom+item+resolver but without knowing the bigger picture, I cannot be sure.

Comment: And this may be what you want to use if you stick to your original plan: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6251/is-it-possible-to-get-page-rendering-result-programmatically